# Dual tracking PSU: how to derive set voltage for second "half"?

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier

I'm fiddling aroud trying to design a dual tracking PSU, based on the LT3080-based design by eevblog/Dave Jones. The general idea is to use a microcontroller obtain \$V_{set}\$ in the range of 0-2V, and then amplify it with an opamp, and use this as set input to the LT3080. Source power is provided by a simple 24V SMPS, and we get a regulated \$V^+\$/\$V^-\$.

I am trying to extend this design with a second, tracking, power supply. So, get a second 24V SMPS, and a second LT3080, and we get an additional output. Let's call these \$V_2^+\$ and \$V_2^-\$, and the outputs of the first half \$V_1^+\$ and \$V_1^-\$. To get **parallel** tracking is fairly easy I think: tie \$V_1^-\$ and \$V_2^-\$ together, and use an opamp to buffer \$V_{set}\$ and use the same architecture to scale it using an opamp.

Where I am struggling is how to switch this configuration to **series** tracking. The first step is to now tie \$V_1^-\$ and \$V_2^+\$ together. To get the correct set input for the second LT3080, we now need to invert \$V_{set}\$ relative to \$V_2^+\$. This led me to the following inverting opamp configuration:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqlcK8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

On the face of it, this seems like it should work. However, \$V_{set}\$ will be higher than \$V_2^+\$, since this is tied to \$V_1^-\$. Will the opamp allow this, or will this lead to escaping magic smoke?

Comment: If everything works ideally, the voltage on the inverting input pin of the op-amp will be equal to v2+, and the output will be V2+ - (Vset - V2+). However, despite the name "rail to rail", op-amps don't always work that well at the rails. Especially, when power is first applied, (or removed) the op-amp might transition through a state that is not healthy for it. I have no idea whether that is a concern that may be dismissed in practice. Others will know better.

Comment: Yeah that's as far as my understanding goes as well, in steady state it should be fine. The problem is, what happens when it transitions to it, will that work? I'm using LM358 opamps btw, those should work fine rail to rail. The inputs can be at most 0.3V above/below the supply voltage. Can I maybe use some kind of clamping scheme to ensure the inputs never raise/drop above/below this 0.3V?